# Adding field to Customer Address and showing it in the admin panel?

Tags: php, magento

I just created an attribute (lastname2) for customer addressess, however I'm not beeing able to show it in the edit address field of the admin panel.

As you can see below I'm setting `used_in_forms` so that it contains `'adminhtml_customer_address'` and `'adminhtml_customer'`, but the field still refuses to appear.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

This is my installer code:

```
<?php
    // update customer address user defined attributes data
    $entityAttributes = array('customer_address'=> array(
            'lastname2' =>  array(
                'store_label'=>'Apellido Materno',
                'label' => 'Apellido Materno',
                'input' => 'text',
                'type'  => 'varchar',
                //System =  False and visible true = Show in 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register'
                'system'=>true,
                'visible'=>true, //Watch out!! Only visible fields get processed by the form controllers!!!
                'user_defined'=>false,
                'used_in_forms' => array('customer_account_create','customer_register_address','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address','adminhtml_customer'),
                'required' => 0,
                'position' =>69
            ),
 );


# Install Attributes
foreach($entityAttributes as $entity=>$attributes)
{
    foreach($attributes as $attribute_code=>$definition)
    {
        $installer->addAttribute($entity, $attribute_code,  $definition); 

        /**
        * @var Mage_Eav_Model_Config
        */
        Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
        ->getAttribute($entity, $attribute_code)
        ->setData('used_in_forms',$definition['used_in_forms'])
        ->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

David, I will suggest you to go through with this nice post [http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address](https://web.archive.org/web/20140327220650/http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address)

I feel you may need to change the address display format as well.

Comment: At the end I managed to get it working. I had to change system to false so it would display it. Excellencemagentoblog is really good, along with Alan Storm's blog and Inchoo :)

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it. It was a dumb mistake. It was a matter of changing `system` from true to false.